# Почему получился бесконечный цикл?

Tags: c++

```
while (answer != 'y' || 'n' != answer) {
  system("cls");
  printf("\nLose.. try again?(y/n)");
  scanf("%c",&answer);
}
```

Это фрагмент кода. Его цель - запрашивать ввод в переменную, до тех пор , пока пользователь не введет любое удовлетворяющие значение, то есть <kbd>n</kbd> или <kbd>y</kbd>. Но я не понимаю почему цикл идет бесконечным путем, так же продолжая спрашивать, после ввода <kbd>y</kbd> или <kbd>n</kbd>.

Цель кода - при вводе y или n цикл должен прерваться, иначе - продолжить

Comment: Вопрос-то, собственно, в чем?

Comment: И где вопрос сам ?

Comment: Кто тут всем минусы ставит??

Answer (score 5):

Если `answer='y'`, то, значит `answer!='n'`, или наоборот. Возможен также вариант, когда ответ не равняется ни `y`, ни `n`. Соответственно, цикл будет запускаться при любых условиях(он будет бесконечен). Так что в ответ на ваш вопрос(который, кстати, не был задан), если вы имели ввиду `y` и `n` как переменные(в чем я сильно сомневаюсь) - пишите без кавычек.

**P.S.: НЕ путайте `&&` и `||`. Это разные вещи!**

Answer (score 4):

Хотя бы одному из них `answer` не равен.
Если он `n`, то не `y`; а если `y`, то не `n`. А в остальных случаях он ни один из них.

В общем, не надо путать `&&` и `||`.

---

Ну и ещё, весьма вероятно, что правильнее написать

```
scanf(" ");
scanf("%c", &answer);
```

но это к (незаданному) вопросу не относится.